# How would you translate "Mentalist" into Latin?

Tags: vocabulary

How would [mentalist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mentalism) be translated into Latin? There is some debate about what constitutes mentalism, but to me I would summarize as the use of psychology, cold reading, skilled intuition, and careful deception to make a subject believe something unreal is real.

This excerpt from Wikipedia also provides more context as to how it's different:

> Some well-known magicians, such as Penn & Teller, and James Randi, argue that a key differentiation between a mentalist and someone who purports to be an actual psychic is that the former is open about being a skilled artist or entertainer who accomplishes their feats through practice, study, and natural means, while the latter may claim to actually possess genuine supernatural, psychic, or extrasensory powers and, thus, operates unethically.

While Latin has words that work for magician, sorcerer, etc, these don't quite capture *mentalist* to me. If you were to explain the concepts above to one of the greats of Latin, what would they call this person? Would they use an existing word or would they borrow *mentalist* into Latin?

Comment: I'm not aware of a pre-existing word in Latin even for a magician as an artist as opposed to someone with real magical powers. I don't think the distinction between a mentalist and a psychic can be made without elaboration in Latin. Thus going through a list of words for different kinds of magicians and picking the aptest ones strikes me as the most reasonable approach. (I'm not even very convinced that most speakers of English are able to make a clear distinction the way professionals like Penn and Teller do.)

Comment: That's definitely fair. I'm really open to whatever is closest, whether it's an existing word that approaches the meaning or simply borrowing the word like any other foreign word.

Comment: @Adam: The description, in your intro, would apply equally well to a successful confidence-trickster: psychology, cold-reading....In  Latin, "fraudator". This may not be what you seek--that guy in the TV-prog who became a complete bore--but it's another angle. The same skills are required; and for (some) politicians, often called "con-men"!

Comment: For some practitioners, that's probably not that far from the truth depending on what their goal is (to entertain vs just get people to hand over money).

Comment: After reading the wikipedia entry, about it, I'm still, somewhat, in the dark, to what a "mentalist" be, but here's my humble guess for a latin (invented) word for it: something from the miniscor family, something with mentor... dēmentor?
Or, you just do, what people do, with living languages, and, simply, adopt the new word: mentalista!

Comment: Adopting a new word is a totally acceptable approach in my case, and it avoids the whole issue of what a mentalist actually is. Feel free to leave that as an answer if you have a moment. :)